# Two rows to one row in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Lets say i have this table

| name | lang | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| welcome | en | Welcome, {user}!... |
| welcome | ko | KoreanMessage1 |
| error | en | Error occurred!.... |
| error | ko | KoreanMessage2 |

so i want to select this table like this:

| name | ko | en |
| --- | --- | --- |
| welcome | KoreanMessage1 | Welcome, {user}!... |
| error | KoreanMessage2 | Error occurred!... |

so how can i do this only with sql?
(i'm using mariadb)

i tried this

```sql
(SELECT
a.name, a.value AS ko, b.value AS en
FROM messages AS a
LEFT JOIN messages AS b
ON a.name = b.name AND a.lang = 'ko' AND b.lang = 'en')
UNION
(SELECT
a.name, a.value AS ko, b.value AS en
FROM messages AS a
RIGHT JOIN messages AS b
ON a.name = b.name AND a.lang = 'ko' AND b.lang = 'en')
ORDER BY name ASC
```

(the table is "message")

and it didnt work.
there was same columns twice.

oh and there might be some data that only in one language but i want to select that too with null on other language.
for example like

| name | ko | en |
| --- | --- | --- |
| welcome | NULL | Welcome! ... |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly try this

```
SELECT m.name,
       msg1.message en,
       msg2.message ko 
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN messages msg1 
    ON msg1.name = m.name 
    AND msg1.lang = 'en' 
LEFT JOIN messages msg2 
    ON msg2.name = m.name 
    AND msg2.lang = 'ko' 
GROUP BY m.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `join` and `group by` to get what you want.

```sql
SELECT m.name, m_en.message en, m_ko.message ko
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN messages m_en ON m_en.name = m.name
INNER JOIN messages m_ko ON m_ko.name = m.name
WHERE m_en.lang = 'en'
AND m_ko.lang = 'ko'
GROUP BY m.name, en, ko
```

Comment: well yeah that kind of works better than mine but as i said:
there might be some data that only in one language but i want to select that too with null on other language.

Comment: It works too. If the default value is NULL you'll get NULL. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdb749/1/0

Comment: oh i meant there might be no row with other language http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03deec/1

Comment: Ok... A bit more complicated! I don't know if it's possible, but I think the best practice is to insert both in all cases, with default value if the message does not exist.

Comment: yeah i was thinking i should change my table design too. well thanks for trying to help anyway!